# How can I write my Jasmine unit tests in CoffeeScript in my Rails 3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, jasmine

Simple, really: I want to write my Jasmine-based JS unit tests in CoffeeScript, but I don’t want to manually compile. Running Jasmine, it doesn’t use the Asset Pipeline for specs.

What’s a good solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, just add **[jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice)**, **[jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine)** to your Gemfile and run **bundle**

create file spec/javascripts/spec.js.coffee with content:

```
#=require_tree ./
```

better visit this [link](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) for more details

Comment: Yes, that does work. It requires a different method of configuration than plain Jasmine, but so far, it’s fine. Thank you.

Comment: It’d also be great if you could take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826828/how-can-i-test-two-very-different-javascript-builds-in-one-rails-project-with-ja)!